# How do I fix the error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'elem *'?

Tags: c++, queue

I was trying to do build my program and it kept giving me the following error:

Error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'elem *'

Problem is that the only way I've found to fix it was to change it to return=0 but that would make the whole thing pointless given that I want it to return 1 when I have successfully removed an element from the queue. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

```
    struct elem { int key;
        elem *next; 
        } *first=NULL, *last=NULL;   

elem *push(int n, elem *&first, elem *&last)  
    { elem *p=last; 
    last=new elem; 
    last->key=n; 
    last->next=NULL; 
    if(p!=NULL) 
        p->next=last; 
    else 
        first=last; 
    } 

elem *pop(int &n, elem *&first, elem *&las) 
           { elem *p=NULL;
           if (first)  
            {       n=first->key; 
                    p=first;  
                    first=first->next;;

                        if (first==NULL) 
                            last=first;  
                         delete p;
                         return 1;       //this here gives me the error
                }      
                else     
                    return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to return `int` when your return type is clearly `elem*`? Choose one option and return either `elem*` or an error code. Also, your `push()` function fails to return anything, which is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Please use a standard indent style.

Comment: Also note that `push` is declared to return an `elem *` but has no return statement -- that's undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

c++ won't let you convert an integral type to a pointer without `reinterpret_cast` or `c-style cast` however your function is misleading and you are doing things that should never be done .

```
char *ptr = 1; // error
char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(0x164651); // compiles but you must make sure this address will be valid !
```

You declare your function to return an `elem *` and makes this an indication to success or failure , In this case you should return `nullptr` on failure and a pointer to the pushed or popped element on success .

```
elem *pop(int &n, elem *&first, elem *&las) 
           { elem *p=NULL;
           if (first)  
            {       n=first->key; 
                    p=first;  
                    first=first->next;;

                        if (first==NULL) 
                            last=first;  
                         return p;       // return the popped element to the caller
                }      


else     
                return nullptr; // failed to pop any element
        }
```

If you insist on indicating success and failure by 1 and 0 values so you should use an integral type as the return type no a pointer.

```
int pop(int &n, elem *&first, elem *&las) // returns 1 on success otherwise 0
```

and in c++ it's more better to use exceptions to indicate failure . This allows to separate failure path from return path and save a lot of error checking which you will find yourself doing most of the time . So Always use c++ exceptions and RAII if possible , it will save you much .

Comment: I'm sorry but I honestly don't understand most of that. Even after trying to translate it to my native language I still don't get it. Would it be a problem if you try to explain it once more?

Comment: Thank you, now  I get it